# Como acceder a este objeto JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

```
"emotion": {
    "document": {
      "emotion": {
        "sadness": 0.202762,
        "joy": 0.46655,
        "fear": 0.569791,
        "disgust": 0.078681,
        "anger": 0.06937
      }
    }
  },
```

Hola, ¿cómo puedo obtener de este objeto la palabra `Sadness` y `Joy`? Haciendo `emotion.document.emotion[0]` no funciona

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias poder obtenerlo haciendo

```
emotion.document.emotion.sadness
emotion.document.emotion.joy
```

`emotion.document.emotion[0]` no funciona porque `emotion.document.emotion` no es un array!

EDIT:

Para obtener el nombre de la key deberias hacer lo siguiente

```
Object.keys(obj.emotion.document.emotion)[0]
```

Fuente: [Object keys - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)

Comment: Hola. No busco obtener el valor de sadness, si no necesito obtener esa palabra.

Comment: @IsaacAlejandro ¿quieres obtener los nombres de las llaves del JSON? Es raro ese requrimiento. Sería como querer obtener algo que ya tienes, pues ya sabes lo que quieres obtener (`sadnes` y `joy`) ¿no? ¿O lo que quieres es saber si el JSON tiene esas claves?

Comment: @IsaacAlejandro Perdon no te habia entendido 

Answer (score 1):

Si haces uso de `keys(Object o)` puedes obtener la lista de claves, y respectivamente con `values(Object o)` la lista de valores.

De este modo puedes obtener todas las claves del objeto:

```js
Object.keys(data.emotion.document.emotion);
```